# single cycle implementation with single memory

Tags: digital-logic, design

I've read that implementing a single cycle cpu requires two memories one for data and one for instructions. Why is this?

Using a single memory with two read ports (see figure below) wouldn't it be possible to fetch the instruction and read the operand specified during the same cycle?

[image]

EDIT:

@supercat

Would something like this work ?

[image]

Comment: Image isn't very clear.

Comment: You should have the rep to be able to upload your own images now. I have done it for you, but you will probably need to re-upload it with better quality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [single-cycle design using and shared memory for both data and instruction](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/26807/single-cycle-design-using-and-shared-memory-for-both-data-and-instruction)

Comment: Yeah I read that question but here I'm giving more details.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you are asking, but you can't fetch a opcode and its operand in the same cycle regardless of memory architecture because you don't know what operand there is to fetch until after the instruction is decoded.  Doing them both together breaks basic cause and effect.

There is was a similar question to this recently.  See [single-cycle design using and shared memory for both data and instruction](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/26807/4512)

Comment: why not ? decoding would be done through a combinational circuit

Comment: @jerry: If memory address 0x1234 contains a "load accumulator from 0x5678" instruction, one cannot simultaneously start the memory fetches from 0x1234 and 0x5678 since one won't know that one needs address 0x5678 until one has read the instruction from 0x1234.  (but see next note)

Comment: It is true that one cannot read the opcode for an instruction at the same time as one fetches the data requested by that instruction (unless one guesses where to read the data, and one's guess turns out to be correct).  On the other hand, there's no problem reading a memory operand requested by one instruction while simultaneously reading the opcode for the *next* instruction.  Unless one is performing jumps based upon the data read from memory, this will yield consistent single-cycle operation.

Answer (score 2):

It would indeed be possible to design a processor to simultaneously fetch code and data from a dual-port memory; indeed, I some Texas Instruments DSP's (and probably some from other vendors) contain some dual-ported RAM that could be used in that fashion.  This is not generally done, however, because dual-ported RAM costs about twice as much per byte as single-ported RAM, and it would generally be more useful to e.g. have a 16K block of memory for data and a 16K block "primarily" for code (likely with a means of reading and writing data, but not necessarily quickly) than to have a 16K block which could be freely used for both code and data with no time penalty.

Answer (score 1):

No that won't work, because if you want to have dual access to the memory you'll have to interleave both accesses, i.e. during one cycle the first request is serviced, and next cycle the other. This would violate the single-cycle requirement.

Comment: I think this is not true if I use a memory like the one you can see in the image.

Comment: What happens in your model if the first user writes to the same address the second user is reading from?

Comment: writing can only occur on rising edge.while reading can occur anytime so everything should be ok.

Comment: Anytime also includes during rising edge. BTW, your (simplified) model doesn't say anything about this.

Comment: The read ports are always open.You can think a word as made up of flip-flops for example.

Comment: @stevenvh: If the memory is synchronous, it may be designed so that writes take immediate effect, or take effect after a consistent one-cycle delay.  If asynchronous, the data sheet will typically specify timing constraints (e.g. minimum time after one port writes an address before the other port can read or write that same address).